# How is antioxidant activity of carotenoids determined?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, food-chemistry

I am doing some research regarding carotenoids and beta-carotene. After extracting the sample, I have not been able to find a way to measure antioxidant activity of beta-carotene. I have $\pu{0.1mM}$ of DPPH (2,2-diphenyl-1-picrylhydrazyl) solution dissolved in methanol, but I just read that you cannot use DPPH to measure beta-carotene free radical inhibition. Is this true? How should I go about doing this?

Comment: You may want to read this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0308814611006108

Comment: Also should read: http://dx.doi.org/10.1155/2013/351671.

Answer (score 4):

As Buck Thorn and I commented elsewhere, the antioxidant activity of carotenoids has been determined using $\ce{DPPH}$ radical ($\ce{DPPH^.}$)(Refs 1 & 2). According to Ref.1, antioxidant activities of the isolated α- and β-carotene have been analyzed in five different concentrations of 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05, and 0.1% ($w/v$) using several assays: The metal chelation, $\ce{DPPH}$ radical scavenging, and superoxide scavenging activities. All of these assays have been showed almost similar results in terms of high activity at lowest concentrations. Thus, it is **not true** that $\ce{DPPH}$ radical assay cannot be use to measure β-carotene free radical inhibition.

For latest information on $\ce{DPPH}$ radical assay, read Ref.3. In general, following is a typical procedure for the assay:

> The $\ce{DPPH}$ assaying of $\beta$-carotene can be performed using known antioxident (*e.g.*, Trolox, ascorbic acid, etc.) as reference compound. The assay can be carried out in either alcoholic media (*e.g.*, methanol or ethanol) or in an aprotic solvent (*e.g.*, acetonitrile). To the degassed solutions ($\pu{2 mL}$) of antioxidant (with a final concentration from $0$ to $\pu{60 μM}$), were added $\pu{2 mL}$ of $\pu{140 μM}$ $\ce{DPPH^.}$ stock solution (70 μM $\ce{DPPH^.}$ final concentration). The solution was stirred at room temperature *in the absence of light*, and, after $\pu{60 min}$, the absorbance was measured at $\pu{517 nm}$ using an UV-vis spectrometer. The working $\ce{DPPH^.}$ concentration was calculated from the absorbance response at $\pu{517 nm}$ of the initial solution in the absence of antioxidant. The $\ce{DPPH^.}$ scavenging percentage or inhibition ($I\%$) was calculated from the measured absorbance using the following expression:
>
> $$I\% = \frac{A-A_0}{A_0}\times 100$$
>   Where $A$ and $A_0$ represent the absorbance at a given antioxidant concentration and the absorbance in the absence of given antioxidant, respectively.

**References:**

1. Lars Müller, Kati Fröhlich, Volker Böhm, “Comparative antioxidant activities of carotenoids measured by ferric reducing antioxidant power (FRAP), ABTS bleaching assay (αTEAC), DPPH assay and peroxyl radical scavenging assay,” *Food Chem.* **2011**, *129(1)*, 139−148 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.foodchem.2011.04.045).
2. Surashree Sen Gupta1, Mahua Ghosh, “*In Vitro* Antioxidative Evaluation of $\alpha$- and $\beta$-Carotene, Isolated from Crude Palm Oil,” *Journal of Analytical Methods in Chemistry* **2013**, Article ID 351671 (10 pages) (http://dx.doi.org/10.1155/2013/351671).
3. Om P. Sharma, Tej K. Bhat, “DPPH antioxidant assay revisited,” *Food Chem.* **2009**, *113(4)*, 1202−1205 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.foodchem.2008.08.008).
4. The most recent reference for $\ce{DPPH}$ assay: Magda M. Becker, Gilvanda S. Nunes, Danilo B. Ribeiro, Francisco E. P. S. Silva, Gaëlle Catanante, Jean-Louis Marty, “Determination of the Antioxidant Capacity of Red Fruits by Miniaturized Spectrophotometry Assays,” *Journal of the Brazilian Chemical Society* **2019**, *30(5)*, 1108-1114 (http://dx.doi.org/10.21577/0103-5053.20190003).